# Visual Studio 2017 + Bitbucket русский язык

Tags: visual-studio-2017, bitbucket

Как настроить Visual Studio 2017 + Bitbucket, чтобы на Bitbucket отображались русские символы?

Comment: utf8 пробовали? или cp1251 не наше все?

Comment: как это сделать для выгрузки кода? Вот так выгруженный русский текст выглядит сейчас: https://bitbucket.org/vilkovsky/trianglelab3/src/master/triangleLab3/Readme.txt
Насколько понимаю должны быть настройки кодировки в параметрах Team Explorer, но там не вижу такого

Comment: Хм, без авторизации на BitBucket отображает нормально. Видимо там проблема

Comment: в студии нужно поменять. И только потом "выгружать".

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, разобрался. Интересно, что отображение не верное, только если авторизован на BitBucket. Для решения надо только выставить тип документа "Документ", а не "Текстовый файл" в настройках файла в Visual Studio.